# DISTINCT ON column only for non null values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How should I declare a query to only use **DISTINCT** on not null values for certain column but still keep the records for which the column value is null, I'm trying to modify the following query:

I'm trying to modify the following query,

[image: distinct]

So, basically I want the second query to return all the messages grouped by `parent_id` when the `parent_id` column **IS NOT NULL** and return **ALL** the records when `parent_id` **IS NULL**.

I'm using PG 9.0.4 and Rails 3.1 - any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is there any order to which you want the parent_id to be returned? Such as the latest message of parent_id=26?  I think I see what you're trying to accomplish, but shouldn't id=29 have a parent_id=26 or is that just the nature of the application?

Comment: Yup messages should be returned with `.order(created_at DESC)`, and I don't get the second part, id=29 has a parent_id=26.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   Select Distinct ON (parent_id) * 
   from messages 
   WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL 
 UNION 
   Select * from messages where parent_id IS NULL
```